# Tengo un problema con el validar de mi login ya que de manera local se ejecuta correctamente pero al momento se subirlo al host no funciona

Tags: php, validación, login

Todo funciona bien de manera local pero cuando intento iniciar sesión desde la web me dice que correo y  contraseña no coinciden, estuve verificando cada variable implicada por separado y todas y la que no se esta ejecutando es la variable $filas...,  cabe aclarar la contraseña esta encriptada en la base de datos de la misma manera en la que utilizamos realizar la consulta, le agradecería mucho al que me pueda ayudar.  anexo el código de validación.

host: 000webhost

```
    <?php
require 'conexion.php';

$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$clave=$_POST['contraseña'];
$clave = hash('sha512', $clave);


 



session_start();
$_SESSION['correo']=$correo;


    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","id19862756_sextante","f^N(cho2JFJQLS{C","id19862756_proyecto");
    
   
    
    $consulta_admin = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo = '$correo' and contraseña='$clave' AND idrol = '1'";
    $resultado_admin = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta_admin);
    $filas_admin = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_admin);

    $consulta_participante = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo = '$correo' and contraseña='$clave' AND idrol = '2'";
    $resultado_participante = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta_participante);
    $filas_participante = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_participante);

    $consulta_colaborador = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo = '$correo' and contraseña='$clave' AND idrol = '3'";
    $resultado_colaborador = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta_colaborador);
    $filas_colaborador =mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_colaborador);
    
    if($filas_admin){
        $_SESSION['usuario']="1"; //administrador
        header("location:login_usuario.php");
        
    }
    else if($filas_participante){ //usuario
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = "2";
        header("location:login_persona.php");
        
    }
    else if($filas_colaborador){//colaborador
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = "3";
        header("location:login_col.php");
        
    }
    else{

   
      
    echo "<script> alert ('El correo o la contraseña no coinciden '); location='/proyecto/index.php' </script>";

        
        
    }'
```

Comment: El campo se llama `contraseña`?  con `ñ`?  quizas no dan soporte para ese caracter en ese hosting o quizas debas forzar la conexión con UTF8... empieza por lo facil y cambia el nombre de ese campo sin la **ñ** en el phpmyadmin y tambien en tu consulta a ver si van por ahi los tiros.